# How to force use of "overflow menu" for actions on header bar?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am using header actions in my Ubuntu SDK app, but I would like to avoid clutter on the header bar.

I have noticed that the Android-style "overflow menu" autocreates itself after a certain number of actions have been added to the header bar, but is there any way to force this to appear?

Example header actions code:

```
head.actions: [
    Action {
        id: reloadAction

        iconName: "reload"
        text: "Reload"

        onTriggered: {
            activityIndicator.running = true
            // do something...
        }
    },
    Action {
        id: aboutAction

        iconName: "info"
        text: "About"

        onTriggered: PopupUtils.open(aboutPopover)
    }
]
```